# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_user.user_id

Tags: python, django-admin, multiple-users

I'm trying to create a multiple user model in django.
I am new to django and as such not in a position to get the exact result I need.

I get an error when trying to createsuperuser.

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

ROLES =(
        ('main', 'Main'),
        ('teacher', 'Teacher'),
        ('student', 'Student'),
        )
```

Here's my register and function

```
def Register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
            last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
            password1 = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            messages.success(request, f'An account has successfully been created for {first_name} {last_name}. Username is {username} and password is {password1}')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})

class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)

class User(AbstractUser):
    user = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ROLES, blank=False, null=False)


class Teacher(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)


class Student(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    first_name  = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    adm = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)

class Main(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
```

My admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User, School

admin.site.register(School)
admin.site.register(User)
```

Trying to create a superuser throws the following traceback

```
(env) D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\Links_Online_Results>python manage.py createsuperuser
Username: ptar
Email address: peterolwande@gmail.com
Password:
Password (again):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_user.user_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 189, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 157, in create_superuser
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 140, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 67, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 790, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 895, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 933, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1254, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1397, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Python\Django\Links Online Exams\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_user.user_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    user = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ROLES, blank=False, null=False)
```

In `User` model, there is a non-nullable field called `user` which is a ForeignKey to `School`.

When creating superuser using django management command, it will ask only for username, email, password.

In this scenario, `user`(aka ForeignKey to School) will be empty which is why it is failing with `user_id` is null.

There are 2 ways to handle this.

1. Make `user` field nullable. With this `createsuperuser` will be able to create new users. Later you can populate `user` field.
2. Write your own management command which takes all required fields to create user and the create a superuser.